# how to use jquery in wordpress menu?

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, menu, menuitem

Im creating a wp theme , I use this code for menu :

```
<?php
$defaults = array(
'theme_location'  => '',
'menu'            => '',
'container'       => 'div',
'container_class' => '',
'container_id'    => '',
'menu_class'      => 'menu',
'menu_id'         => '',
'echo'            => true,
'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
'before'          => '',
'after'           => '',
'link_before'     => '',
'link_after'      => '',
'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
'depth'           => 0,
'walker'          => '');  wp_nav_menu( $defaults );?>
```

and the output Html code is somthing like this :

```
<div class="menu-%d9%81%d9%87%d8%b1%d8%b3%d8%aa-%db%b1-container">
  <ul id="menu-%d9%81%d9%87%d8%b1%d8%b3%d8%aa-%db%b1" class="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-12"
    class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-12">

      <a href="http://localhost/soheil/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-14" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-14">
      <a href="http://localhost/soheil/?page_id=10">
        <span>M item1</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-13" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-13">
          <a href="http://localhost/soheil/?page_id=2">ch item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-98" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-98">
          <a href="http://localhost/soheil/?page_id=89">ch item 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-99" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-99">
      <a href="http://localhost/soheil/?page_id=2">
        <span>ch item 4</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-100"
    class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-100">
      <a href="http://localhost/soheil/?page_id=89">ch item 5</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-103" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-103">
          <a href="http://localhost/soheil/?page_id=72">ch item 6</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-104" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-104">
          <a href="http://localhost/soheil/?page_id=27">ch item 7</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li id="menu-item-105"
    class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-105">
      <a href="http://localhost/soheil/?page_id=26">ch item 8</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-106" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-106">
          <a href="http://localhost/soheil/?page_id=25">
            <span>ch item 9</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-107" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-107">
          <a href="http://localhost/soheil/?page_id=24">
            <span>ch item 10</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-108" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-108">
          <a href="http://localhost/soheil/?page_id=21">
            <span>ch item 11</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-109" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-109">
          <a href="http://localhost/soheil/?page_id=10">
            <span>ch item 12</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-110" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-110">
          <a href="http://localhost/soheil/?page_id=2">
            <span>ch item 13</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now I want to create a kind of menu that if user clicks on a category, list id sub menu for that will be opend! 
for this I use this jquery code :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("ul li").hover(function(){
      $("ul li > ul li").animate({right: '300px'}); 
 });});
```

(Not exactly this code) But the problem is that wen I hover one item , all `ul li ul li` items are affect and move ! 
how can I Specify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WP I think the best way to interact with menus is using it's native classes that are meant for that purpose!

ex. if you want to show a submenu of the specific item when hovering it, simply use the following:

```
$('.menu-item-has-children').on('mouseover',function(){
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').show();
}).on('mouseleave',function(){
    $(this).children('.sub-menu').hide();
});
```

Here's the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/905dvre0/)

edit to the users request:

```
   $('.menu-item-has-children').on('click',function(){
        $(this).children('.sub-menu').show();
       return false;
    }).on('mouseleave',function(){
        $(this).children('.sub-menu').hide();
    });
```

This will make sub-menus open on click, but will close them after you put your mouse away of them

Comment: thank you , do you Know how can I apply this abilty : I Want  user when clicks on Mother items, It wont act ! you know I just want when user click on Mother items just the list will be opend ! and it wlii not be a link

Comment: I am really appreciate for your help it works great thank you so much  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the sub menu for the hovered item by narrowing down by class specifier. In hover event callback, you can obtain the hovered item DOM object as `this`, so you'll have `.sub-menu` as its sibling. Then, you do something on that sub menu.

```
$( ".menu-item a" ).hover(
    function()
    {
        $( this ).siblings( ".sub-menu" )
                 .animate( { "right": "300px" } );
    }
);
```